# Yii query with error for composite unique key

Tags: php, sql, yii

Yii CMS

I have a unique composite key in the table 'category', website_id + link,  and Yii does not support this keys, so I wrote my own method

a website has many links, each unique;
2 or more websites may have the same link; because the link may not be absolute;

from a array of links, I extract one link at a time, and if the category pattern fits, I want to store the url;

```
preg_match('/\/popular\/(.*?)\/1\.html/ims', $matches_website_url[1], $matches_url);

if(count($matches_url) > 0 &&
    $this->avoid_duplicate_category($website['id'], $matches_url[1]) )
{
    $category = new Category();
    $category->website_id = $website['id'];
    $category->link = $matches_url[0];
    $category->name = $matches_url[1];
    $category->urls = 0;
    $category->update = time();
    $category->save();
}
```

and the method

```
private function avoid_duplicate_category($website_id,$link)
{
    $query_category = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select * from `category` where `website_id`='.$website_id.' and `link`='.$link.';");

    $results = $query_category->queryAll();

    if(count($results)>0)return false;
    else return true;

}
```

and the error returned :

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Cute' for key 'name'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `category` (`website_id`, `link`, `name`, `urls`, `update`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to allow Yii to handle the composite key by adding the following to your model:

```
public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('website_id','link');
}
```

EDIT,

Sorry, misread your question! For unique keys (not primary) you could try these extensions:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/composite-unique-key-validatable/

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/unique-index-validator

Comment: this is not the Pk, is a un ique key; i think that i can rename the method, and yii will accept it; i hope; wait until i try;

Comment: public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
...
            array('website_id, link', 'primaryKey'),
...
        );
    }

    public function primaryKey() {
        return array('website_id', 'link');
    }

Comment: yeah, sorry misread your question! I've added a link to a couple of extensions that might help you

Comment: ok, but why my method does not work ? why does it return true even if the data is a duplicate ? yii recomends somethign to complex for me

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:

```
private function avoid_duplicate_category($website_id,$link)
{
    $query = "select * from `category` where `website_id`=:website_id and `link`=:link;";

    $query_category = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);

    $query_category->bindParam( ':website_id', $website_id);

    $query_category->bindParam( ':link', $link);

    $results = $query_category->queryAll();

    if(count($results)>0)return false;
    else return true;

}
```